# What Linux distro is good for music and well supported?

Tags: audio, alsa, jack

I'm pretty disappointed with Ubuntu. It's never been easy to sort out the mess that is Alsa / Jack / whatever and have it work with Pd, Supercollider, Ardour, Lillypad.

I've upgraded to the latest and a) it immediately broke some audio software I was writing in openFrameworks (just stopped compiling, complaining about rtaudio), b) there seems to be no real-time kernel any more, and c) the audio I did get working is noisy.

Does anyone out there make and support a good Linux distro that "just works" (ie. sets up whatever needs to be set up in terms of Alsa / Jack / etc.) that ensures that my (in principle) fast computer can actually generate clean sound?

If not, what's the impediment? Is there some reason that audio can't be brought under control the way that different GUIs were in the past?

Answer (score 3):

[Ubuntu Studio](http://ubuntustudio.org/). Dan of the Linux Outlaws podcast fame uses it for his podcast and music production.

Comment: I was somewhat put off by reading this. http://ubuntustudio.org/Oneiric+Ocelot

I still value most of what I get in Ubuntu Ocelot. But it sounds like Ubuntu Studio want to fork away from it but don't really have the manpower.

Answer (score 1):

[AV Linux](http://www.bandshed.net/AVLinux.html) - optimised nimble Linux with lots of plugins and the newest version of Ardour. You can even test out the new Ardour3 beta with Midi support.

Sadly the guy who made is stopping to make any new versions for the next time - but right now everything works really fine.